# Overriding Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer class not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, overrides, layered-navigation

> Overriding `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer` class not working in Magento 2.

I'm trying to create a custom module for showing custom product collection with layered navigation.

here i added `di.xml` file to overwrite model using `preference`.

But its not working, i tried to create log also, no log generated.

***\app\code\Mage\Search\etc\di.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer" type="Mage\Search\Model\Layer" />
</config>
```

***Layer.php***

```
namespace Mage\Search\Model;

class Layer extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{

   public function getProductCollection()
    {
        /*added log here*/
        var_dump('test'); // nothing showed.
        die(); // this also not helped
        if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
            $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
        } else {
            $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
            $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
            $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
        }

        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Please suggest any solution for this.

Thank you!

Comment: hello. have you added di under frontend folder?

Comment: no, added under etc `\app\code\Mage\Search\etc\di.xml`

Comment: add into  \app\code\Mage\Search\etc\frontend\di.xml file

Comment: @SunilPatel let check and let you know

Comment: make sure you flush cache, generation and di

Comment: @SunilPatel i got error  `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface`

Comment: can you please write both file code?

Comment: @SunilPatel i already added both file code in question

Comment: have you created constuct methd? if yes then share

Comment: @SunilPatel i am not added construct method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59344/discussion-between-dhanabal-and-sunil-patel).

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @dhanabal please check Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer is not a class in Magento2

Answer (score 1):

You should extend \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category or \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search class, like this:

In your etc/di.xml add:

```
...
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category" type="[Vendor]\[Your_Extension]\Model\Override\Layer\Category" />
<type name="[Vendor]\[Your_Extension]\Model\Override\Layer\Category">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="context" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\Context</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
...
```

Create your model with your new or overrided functions in [Vendor][Your_Extension]\Model\Override\Layer\Category:

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Your_Extension]\Model\Override\Layer;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel;

class Category extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
    /**
     * @param $context
     * @param StateFactory $layerStateFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $layerStateFactory,
            $attributeCollectionFactory,
            $catalogProduct,
            $storeManager,
            $registry,
            $categoryRepository,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function newFunction($param1){
        //Your code here
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working :( I want to override getProductCollection() from Layer.php

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ContextInterface;

class Layer  extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer
{
...................
}
```